# C# Preprocessor Macro Alternative

Tags: c#, macros, c-preprocessor, pinvoke

I'm wrapping a native library with hundreds of function and its totally annoying to type that DllImport above all of those functions.

Is there a way to avoid writing these ugly/repeated attributes above every function ?

```
public const string NativeDll = "mynativelib.dll";

[DllImport(NativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void foo1();

[DllImport(NativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void foo2();

[DllImport(NativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void foo3();

[DllImport(NativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void foo4();

...

[DllImport(NativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void fooN();
```

Comment: Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V. There is no way in C#, however you can write the wrapper in managed C++ and use the DLLs header files directly. That's what managed C++ is for.

Comment: thanks but i want to use this wrapper under mono/linux , so  C++/CLI is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not have a pre-processor, so the simple answer to your question is that it is not possible to avoid writing the attribute for every p/invoke declaration.

Now, you could write your own pre-processor or script to generate these p/invoke declarations. I'm not convinced that would be worth the effort since p/invoke declarations tend to get written once only and require no maintenance.

Comment: C# doesn't have a stand alone pre-processor, but it has [the functionality of one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx). It is very limited in comparison to some other languages, though.